# Is considering a user's track record before voting to close considered acceptable?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, policy, code-of-conduct

On History Stack Exchange, we have a policy of heightened scrutiny on questions that involve certain controversial topics due to the frequency with which these topics are used by trolls. One [formulation](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3684/21290) of the policy is as such:

> Questions on these topics have a hair-trigger for being put on hold. This goes in particular for new users who don't have a proven track-record of asking good questions.

While this policy can in theory be applied to various controversial topics, in practice it is all about Adolf Hitler, Nazism, and the Holocaust. We regularly get Holocaust-denialists trying to push their views and general trolls posting inflammatory questions just to get a response, so the reaction has been to close Nazi-related questions unless it is *clear* that the poster is asking in good faith (as opposed to leaving them open unless it can be established that the poster is posting in bad faith as is done with less controversial topics).

In general I think this is a good policy, but it does strike me as odd is that we seem to be saying that the decision whether to vote to close a potentially problematic question may be determined **based on a review of the poster's other contributions**. This seems to be getting very close to targeted action - saying, "Hey, your post appears barely acceptable and I wasn't going to vote to close it, but it turns out I don't like what you've posted in the past so I'm going to vote to close anyway.".

While everyone seems to be using this policy responsibly at the moment, I fear that this could lead to abuse in the future, with new users potentially being told, "I voted to close your question because although it looks good at first glance, I don't trust you well enough to ask a good question so there must be something wrong with it that I can't see. Come back when you have a better question record."

In other words, when we check the user's other contributions before deciding whether to vote to close, we are *voting on the user rather than the content*. That's what gives me pause.

So, is this sort of policy acceptable? If not, how can we modify it to keep our site free of bad questions without running "background checks" on marginal cases?

To be clear, I'm not asking about a general "Nazi question policy" but simply using that as an example. The question I'm asking could equally apply to other controversial subjects. For example, a question on the side effects of COVID-19 vaccines on Medical Sciences.SE might be treated differently if the poster has a record of asking science denialist questions.

Comment: I don't see how it's much different than the automated systems which block users from asking until they can further prove they are capable of asking good questions. It's just performing the block after the question was asked instead of before.

Comment: Iirc there’s a policy to be more careful when using spam flags on established users posts, which is probably related.

Comment: We do a similar thing on Puzzling for our "needs attribution" close reason. A longtime user won't get questions or close-votes because we assume their puzzle is original. However, newer users, or those with a history of posting non-original puzzles, would be more likely to get close-votes and general scrutiny about attribution.

Comment: The votes are not based on the _user_ but instead on the content (or lack thereof) that they have contributed to the community. No track record means no way to gauge, so better to err on the side of caution around such topics.

Comment: Technically we do that here on MSE (if you don't want us making excuses, or being opaque). A clearly reasonable use is if they ask an almost identical question to their prior question, the new is closed as a duplicate of the old. Where *we* are a bit more liberal is when they've posted a prior closed question, and especially if they've argued to the bitter end in the comments, and they write a ***new question*** that's not quite the same as the prior one but it's clearly crafted to regurgitate the prior subject - that's abusive and time wasting, usually resulting in closure.

Comment: I've upvoted even though I disagree this treads the line of judging a post by who wrote it instead of by its content. This is a good discussion to have. I do think conflating close votes and up/down votes is a mistake though. Salvaging a borderline question is a lot easier with cooperation from its author.

Comment: Related: *[Godwin's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin's_law)*

Answer (score 20):

SE sites are communities, and it is perfectly reasonable that past actions be factored into decisions on how much leeway to give a user when it comes to borderline questions that may be more disruptive than informative.

If a user is unfamiliar with the community, closing their question while it is improved to be more obviously on-topic is helpful. Closing a borderline question by someone who has a history of trying to gin up a lot of drama until it can be reworked into something less inflammatory is perfectly reasonable. If a mistake is made, the question can always be reopened. Closing is not as drastic an action as deleting.

Answer (score 2):

No, this policy is not acceptable. I recommend removing the part that says "This goes in particular for new users who don't have a proven track-record of asking good questions". Here's why.

- **Most visitors who view a post do not know the author** and the author's history of contributions to Stack Exchange.
- Posts should be reviewed (and closed if needed) in a way that is detached as much as possible from the nature of the post's author. People have biases. Reviewers are people. Therefore, reviewers are biased. **Unbiased review by definition is the one that does not consider the nature of the author, but considers the post alone.**
- **I try to ignore the author when reviewing the posts in the queue.** I formulate the response in my mind **before** looking at who created the post. I most *certainly* ignore the author's rep and badges. A bad post is bad even when asked by a great contributor. A good post is good even when asked by a new contributor, or a contributor with a bad track record. **A post is just a post.**
- **It's simpler and more robust to look at the post alone, without also reviewing the author's history on SE, if any.** How do you know when to stop when reviewing the history? Last 3 posts? 30? 300? Why stop with SE, and not also google the author to see if they have posted anything on Twitter or Reddit? How deep do you dig that rabbit hole? My rabbit hole is shallow and simple: one post, **this** post.

Comment: While I admit that I did not have a chance to encounter Holocaust denial trolls on SE, I have seen a fair number of [all kinds of other troll posts on Parenting.SE](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1432/33055), where they are dispatched upon detection both swiftly and humanely.

Comment: Under the standard of "preponderance of the evidence" prior same conduct is fair, it's only under a criminal trial that prior acts would not be introduced without a voir dire; in any event I'm not held to those standards here, and the one affected can simply ask for their question to be reopened - a decision that I'd be excluded from, having been involved in the prior action. --- Sources: https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/preponderance_of_the_evidence or https://dictionary.law.com/default.aspx?selected=1586 --- All decisions are subject to a reasonable number of appeals.

Comment: This answer is good in principle, but in practise the post does not always give complete information needed to determine if it is suitable. A borderline post by a good contributor is likely to become better with a few clarifications that show the intentions of the author, while the exact same borderline post by a troll is likely to get worse and in need of deletion. IMO this warrants a "benefit of the doubt" approach for known good contributors and at the same time a "close/delete fast" approach for new contributors, even if the contents of the post is the same.

Comment: I don’t think ignoring context is a way to make a good decision. Remember this is not for every question, just for questions about controversial topics that aren’t clearly on-topic.

Comment: @ColleenV How deep should you dig for context? Unless this is clearly specified, it is open to biased interpretation. Last 3 posts? Last 30? Google the author and try to find their Reddit or Twitter posts? An enterprising reviewer with enough time and enough bias might be able to find historical evidence to support any decision!

Comment: @Rob SE is a Q&A site, not a court room. And the legal standards may not necessarily apply here. Plus, in a court room not any user with enough rep is allowed to comment on the case. Not sure if you were aware of that. But your comment is very welcome, seriously. Thank you!

Comment: @Marijn Every good contributor started once upon a time with low rep as a new user. What gives?

Comment: Tim ur, you misunderstood or stopped reading my comment ~30 words in.

Comment: Good contributors start as new users, but the current discussion is only about borderline quality questions on very controversial topics. For all other topics also new contributors can get the benefit of the doubt. The "user factor" even works opposite in that case I think: for a new contributor the community is in many cases more forgiving about quality issues than for experienced contributors, at least on smaller sites.

Comment: @Timur You use your judgement. How far do you go when verifying the content in the post is accurate? Do you verify the credentials of authors of any papers linked to by calling the university they attended? We aren’t writing a computer algorithm; we’re offering guidance for people who can think for themselves.

Comment: @ColleenV Any investigations into the author open the doors for bias wider than is optimal. The posts should be analyzed on their own merit.   Encourage confirming the accuracy of the post. Discourage analysis of the author’s prior work and history. The post should stand or fall on its own merit, not because of the author’s merits.

Comment: @TimurShtatland If I'm confronted with a post that looks like its only purpose is to troll people and have to decide whether a valid question that just needs a little work to be on-topic and constructive or if it's a waste of everyone's time, I'm going to look at the author's profile to help me make that decision. I'm also going to look at how they responded to any feedback that was left for them about their question, whether they made any edits to address that feedback etc. To suggest that by doing that I'm making a worse decision than if I hadn't is just not reasonable.